# How to scale pink box so that it will fit perfectly in the grid of spreadsheet no matter the screen size of phone? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH8Oc.png)

The pink box is a tablelayout and the spreadsheet is a constraint layout. I have tried using margins and constraints but when I run it on different phones, the pink box always ends up outside or will be too small. Code right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/game1"
    android:maxWidth="500dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:foreground="#CBD81B60"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `constraintlayout.widget.Guideline` and use `layout_constraintGuide_percent` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/game1">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".2"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".1"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".9"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:foreground="#CBD81B60"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guide_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide_start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guide_top"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

you can change layout_constraintGuide_percent as you wish

hope this help